# Не загружаются все элементы сцены в SubScene

Tags: java, javafx

Есть субсцена, на нее устанавливается сцена во время инициализации контроллера (subscene.setRoot()), всё работает нормально, но когда я пытаюсь изменить субсцену где-либо кроме метода initialize контроллера субсцена полностью окрашивается в цвет, который указан в subscene.setFill(), если установить заливку на null, то отображаются какие-то дочерние элементы, но не все.

Загрузка в методе initialize:

[image: initialize]

Загрузка через ивент клика мышкой на какой-либо объект:

[image: other]

Код:

```
public void initialize() {
    //РАБОЧИЙ КОД:
    try {
        System.err.println(Platform.isFxApplicationThread()); // TRUE
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(Main.class.getResource("front/resources/fxml/login.fxml")));
        subscene.setRoot(root);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //НЕ РАБОЧИЙ КОД
    settingsLeftPane.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        try {
            System.err.println(Platform.isFxApplicationThread()); // TRUE
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(Main.class.getResource("front/resources/fxml/login.fxml")));
            subscene.setRoot(root);
            subscene.setFill(null);
            System.err.println(subscene.getFill());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```